# How to redirect NGINX to if

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a redirect with nginx, which if it returns /?SSO=1 it redirects to https://support.com.br/?SSO=1 but if it returns to /?SSO=0, the url goes to just https://support.com.br/ my code is like this

```
map $arg_SSO $ssorewrite {
    0  /;
    1  /?SSO=1;
}
server {
    listen 8080;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    rewrite ^/$ /?SSO=1 permanent;
    port_in_redirect off;

    if ($arg_SSO) {
        rewrite ^/$ $ssorewrite last;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;    
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
    location ~ php-errors\.log$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

however, it is redirecting from this: https://support.com.br/ for: https://support.com.br/?SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1&SSO=1

the idea is to redirect from https://support.com.br/ to https://support.com.br/?SSO=1 and if it returns ?SSO=0 or another value, redirect it to the url https://support .com.br/ how can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this map construction:

```
map $arg_SSO $ssorewrite {
    0  /;
    1  /?SSO=1;
}
```

also in virtual host config:

```
server {
...
    if ($arg_SSO) {
        rewrite ^/$ $ssorewrite last;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253643/nginx-redirect-url-but-duplicated